# MVC Partial Methods with dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

**ASP.NET MVC 2**

I'm trying to write a view whose generic parameter is `dynamic`, and then pass this dynamic model to a partial view

```
<%@ Page Title="" ..... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
```

and then

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("MenuTabsPartial", Model); %>
```

but I'm getting the error

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'RenderPartial' but appears to have an extension method by that name ...

**I am fully aware that extension methods cannot be dispatched with dynamic parameters.**

My question is, is there some sort of MVC-specific work around?

This extension method has to be defined in a public static calss somewhere, right?  Is it possible to invoke RenderPartial from *there*, like you can with linq:

```
Enumerable.Where(stringArray, s => s.StartsWith("Adam"));
```

Comment: It seems it's declared in the [RenderPartialExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492211.aspx) class.

Comment: @JohnH - sweet.  Any idea where RenderAction is declared?  There's no RenderActionExtensions class and google is unhelpful at the moment

Comment: You're in luck!  [ChildActionExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721299.aspx).

Comment: @John - please put both those links in an answer so I can score you 25 glorious rep (I'll even add some code in for you so the flag police don't delete the answer)

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll add those now.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find `RenderPartial` in [RenderPartialExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492211.aspx) and `RenderAction` in [ChildActionExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721299.aspx).

So to call these methods with a dynamic parameter, you'd do:

```
<% RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(Html, "MenuTabsPartial", Model); %>
```

and

```
<% ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(Html, "List", Model); %>
```